# Snowboard Storage

Tags: garage, shelving, storage, shelf

I want to store my snowboard as follows:

1. Put 4 x 12" rods straight out from the wall, only 1" from the ceiling
2. Slide board onto rods, underside of board along the ceiling (bindings down between the rods)

What kind of 'rods' should I use, and how do I get them into the wall?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance about snowboarding, but it would be helpful to know how much your snowboard weighs, and the approximate dimensions.

Answer (score 3):

Screw pipe flanges into the studs, screw pieces of pipe into the flanges. You'll probably want to clean the pipe or paint it, as it usually has an oily residue. If the studs don't line up where you want the rods you can screw a 2x4 to the wall then screw the flanges to the 2x4. [image]

Comment: Good solution! I would add that you might want to add a 2x4 or 2x6 anyway to mount the flanges. That way you'll be able to get all four screws into solid wood and it will better protect the walls. If you prefer the look of wood I have mounted skis on 1" dowels inserted into a 2x6 mounted on the wall. Worked great.

Comment: And put a pool noodle or pipe insulation over the metal pipe to keep the snowboard from getting scratched.